# How to generate debug symbols for linux-x.x.x if it is not available?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to use [SystemTap](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Systemtap) to hack kernel, linux-4.13.4.

I install it by following this [post](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Systemtap), I get stuck in

> Where to get debug symbols for kernel X?
>   http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/

Since I use my compiled kernel version `4.13.4`, however, there is no corresponding version for `linux-4.13.4`.

I want to follow the instructions

> How do I build a debuginfo kernel if one isn't available?

```
Getting the sources and compiling the kernel on Ubuntu.

$ cd $HOME
$ sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev debhelper gawk
$ mkdir tmp
$ cd tmp
$ sudo apt-get build-dep --no-install-recommends linux-image-$(uname -r)
$ apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
$ cd linux-2.6.31 (this is currently the kernel version of 9.10)
$ fakeroot debian/rules clean
$ AUTOBUILD=1 fakeroot debian/rules binary-generic skipdbg=false
$ sudo dpkg -i ../linux-image-debug-2.6.31-19-generic_2.6.31-19.56_amd64.ddeb
```

But, I get some problems when I do `sudo apt-get build-dep --no-install-recommends linux-image-$(uname -r)`

> ERROR:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for linux-image-4.13.4
```

I am concerned about debug symbols since I will add some codes in kernel-4.13.4. If I use the version `4.13.0` from http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/, what if after I add code in `4.13.3` but `4.13.0` is not available since the version is different and the symbol cannot be found?

Does it matter if I use `4.13.0` in http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/ even if I modify code in `linux-4.13.4`?

If it does matter, how can I eliminate the problem and generate my customized dbgsym version of `linux-4.13.4`?

Reference:

https://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/SystemtapOnUbuntu

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Systemtap

http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/